# shared_ptr doesn't increase reference count, but point at the same address

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

here is my code snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

class A
{

 public:

  int a = 100;

  A()
  {
    std::cout << "Create A" << std::endl;
  }

  ~A()
  {
    std::cout << "Release A" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual void printer() = 0;

};

std::list<std::shared_ptr<A>> arr;

class B : public A
{

 public:

  int b = 1000;

  ~B()
  {
    std::cout << "Release B" << std::endl;
  }

  void printer() override
  {
    std::cout << "B's printer" << std::endl;
  }

  B()
  {
    std::shared_ptr<A> tmp(this);
    arr.push_back(tmp);
    (*arr.begin())->printer();
    std::cout << "inside B's c'tor test B counts: " << tmp.use_count()
              << std::endl;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::shared_ptr<B> B_ptr = std::make_shared<B>();
  std::shared_ptr<A> A_ptr(B_ptr);
  std::cout << "list address:  " << (*arr.begin()).get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test B address: " << B_ptr.get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test A address: " << A_ptr.get() << std::endl;

  std::cout << "list counts:  " << (*arr.begin()).use_count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test B counts: " << B_ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "test A counts: " << A_ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My expectation is: A's reference count should be three, but only got 2. I think when I push_back to the list, there should be a temporarily created share_ptr object, even it is get destroyed, the one in list should also pointing to the same address as A_ptr and B_ptr. It turns out that they (those three), did pointing at the same address, but use_count got different results. `(*arr.begin()).use_count()` is 1, the others are both 2.

Why? Please help.

Ps: I know turning this pointer to share_ptr is stupid operation, but the result doesn't make sense and even disobey the syntax.

Comment: You may find some things to fix if you compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and run the program. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/48Edx5cf6)

Comment: But why it doesn't match the reference count?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's relevant as long as the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: i know where the error comes from. After releasing A_ptr and B_ptr, according to the output, the address of these two share_ptr is already with count=0; but list's first element is pointing to the same address as those two, then issue comes out. This is exactly the thing confusing me. Those 3 are all share_ptr pointing to the same address, but have the different ref count.

Comment: You may want to read about [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and the potential problems it may solve. _"`enable_shared_from_this` provides the safe alternative to an expression like `std::shared_ptr<T>(this)`, which is likely to result in this being destructed more than once by multiple owners that are unaware of each other"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My expectation is: A's reference count should be three, but only got 2.

Your expectation is wrong. You only made one copy of the shared pointer, so the use count is 2.

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<A> tmp(this);
> ```

On this line you transfer the ownership of a bare pointer that you don't own into a new shared pointer. Since this was already owned by another shared pointer, the behaviour of the program will be undefined when the two separate owners attempt to destroy it.

---

Creating a shared pointer from this is possible using `std::enable_shared_from_this`, but it's not simple.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I misunderstand a thing on shared_ptr, which is not relevant to the pointed address, but the ownership